# Loading CSV into DataGridView

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, odbc

Here is my code to load a CSV file into a my DataGridView in my WinForms application:

```
private void loadCSV(string path)
{
  if (!File.Exists(path))
  {
    MessageBox.Show(this, "File does not exist:\r\n" + path, "No File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    return;
  }

  try
  {
    string conStr = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=C:;Extensions=csv,txt";
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(conStr);
    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("Select * from " + path, conn);

    dt = new DataTable(path);
    da.Fill(dt);

    this.path = path;
    dataGridView.DataSource = dt;

    da.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(this, "There was an error loading the CSV file:\r\n" + ex.Message, "IO Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
  }
}
```

It works for almost all valid CSV files, except ones in folders with certain characters.

e.g. it will work for

- C:\Users\Public\Desktop\MyCSV.csv

but not for

- C:\Users\Public\Desktop\My Folder\MyCSV.csv

Anybody know how I can fix it? I assume I need to somehow augment the conStr.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not work', and for what characters? Could you post the error?

Comment: 42S02 "The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object"

Comment: sir can you help if. if i can create a csv file from my datagriview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your select statement to

```
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("Select * from [" + path + "]", conn);
```

The spaces in the filename will wrote it off.

Comment: I just changed the line as per your instructions, but I'm still getting an error: 42S02 "The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object"...

Comment: In your connection string, change `Dbq=`' to the folder you are working in, and in the select statement do a `SELECT * FROM [some filename.csv]`.

Comment: This ended up working: `string conStr = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetFullPath(path)) + ";Extensions=csv,txt";` and `OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("Select * from [" + Path.GetFileName(path) + "]", conn);`

Comment: sir i am investigating for backing up the data of winform. so i thought to make csv file. so can i create csv file from datagridview data?